# Public Pair application STATUS DATE

Tags: status, public, pair, date

and thanks for your assistance.  Is the STATUS DATE listed for an application on Public Pair the date the STATUS action happened or just the date it was last updated?
My confusion lies in an 2007 application (11/811041) where the STATUS is "FINAL REJECTION MAILED" but the status date is December 2017, 10 years later.

I'm wondering what the real status of the application is.  If the final rejection was truly December 2017, it may well still be live as unlikely as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If you look it up in Public PAIR and click on the Image File Wrapper tab, you will see -

> 03-27-2018    N/AP    Notice of Appeal Filed

Rather than responding with a RCE/response/amendment to the final rejection, the application has filed for the first steps of an appeal. Along the way it has had other "final" rejections and also went abandoned briefly in 2010.

Comment: You can check something to indicate you select my answer and I get points. I don't really need points.

Comment: Hi George, I checked the counter to give you a point. I says it will be recorded, but since I'm new, it won't help your points score.  Thanks for the help though and know that it has been "recorded"!

Comment: @EricAdvance If the answer suits you, you should check the checkmark which "accepts" the answer. This will give George White even more points than an up vote.